# Programmatic UIView inside TableView Header

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I am putting a UIView programmatically inside my TableView Header.

But, the header view is being blocked by the Navigation Controller bar and won't go any bigger in height.

Here is my code:

```
let headerView = UIView()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.000, green: 0.749, blue: 1.000, alpha: 1.00)
    headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: view.frame.width, height: 200)
    return headerView
}
```

**What is working:**

1. The TableView loads.
2. A "Blue" header appears that looks to be about 10px big and is stuck at the top of the TableView
3. This "Blue" header is being blocked by the Navigation Controller bar.

**What isn't working:**

1. The "Blue" header is not changing its height.
2. The "Blue" header won't come down any lower.

Comment: note: this is not table header, but section. Use tableView.tableHeaderView property instead and then setting frames will work

Comment: @KK7 do you think you could provide an answer with some code, please? Sorry, I'm only new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this!

```
var headerView = UIView()
headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.000, green: 0.749, blue: 1.000, alpha: 1.00)
headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: view.frame.width, height: 200)
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView // Here goes the UIView for the header
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two ways:

1. Using `viewForHeaderInSection` dataSource and `heightForHeaderInSection` delegate methods.
2. But if you're going to have one header and you don't need the 'sticky' section header functionality I suggest to use:

   ```
   let tableHeaderView = UIView()
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()        
       tableHeaderView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 200)
       tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView
   }
   ```

Note: if you're going for 2 approach, `viewForHeaderInSection` in your case is redundant and therefore you should remove it.